# I have two responsive menus--how can I edit the javascript to close one when the other is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have two responsive menus on a page similar to the jsfiddle below. When you minimize the window to see the responsive "Menu" text links, currently when one is opened and you click the other, they both stay open. How would I edit the javascript so when one opens, the other closes? Thanks so much for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jq6sZ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('js');
      var $menu = $('#menu'),
          $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
          $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a');

    $menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
    });

    $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });

    });$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('js');
      var $menu = $('#menu2'),
          $menulink = $('.menu-link2'),
          $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a');

    $menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
    });

    $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selector.removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

this means remove class active on any of the selector but give this the class active.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anything you'd do to clean this code up? I struggle with javascript and this is kind of hacked together.